# My application is implementing a Google map capabiity. I amd getting a location permission error on

Tags: java, android

I am implementing a Google Map into my application which includes setting the current location of the user.  I have added the  ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION into the application manifest and my gradle file uses a minimum SDK of 23.  The device emulator that I am running is also 23.

My understanding is that with version 23 I do not need to ask for permission, as that is handled with the app installation or upgrade.

The application is crashing saying that I need to allow location access (see attached logcat entry).  It is on the statement (line 64) on the attached MapsActivity.java

```
  mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

**MapAcitivity.java**

```
package com.grgapps.checkingin;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback ,
        OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final String MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey";
    private MapView mMapView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY); }
        //mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        //mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Gordon and move the camera
        LatLng gordon = new LatLng(46.218972, -91.910414);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(gordon).title("Home"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(gordon));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        //UiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this::onMyLocationButtonClick);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this::onMyLocationClick);
    }


    public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Current location:\n" + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (mapViewBundle == null) {
            mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
            outState.putBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        }
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (PermissionUtils.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            // Enable the my location layer if the permission has been granted.
            enableMyLocation();
        } else {
            // Permission was denied. Display an error message
            // ...
        }
    }
    private void enableMyLocation() {
        // [START maps_check_location_permission]
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            // Permission to access the location is missing. Show rationale and request permission
            PermissionUtils.requestPermission(this, 0,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, true);
        }
    }
/*
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mMapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
*/
}
```

**Application Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.grgapps.checkingin">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAPQCMFgUWQp4RSDDO0EjpCPuDLhTUjcfg" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps_and_directions"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        </activity>
        <!--
         Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages.

        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <!--
 Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
             notification message. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Emergency"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_emergency"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Contacts"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PeepsLocator"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_peeps_locator"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RequestCheckIn"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_request_check_in"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewCheckIns"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_view_check_ins"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RoadTrip"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_road_trip"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Commute"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_commute"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CheckIn"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_check_in"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CheckInNew"
            android:label="CheckInNew"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Logcat entry**

```
03-18 06:27:54.442 5342-5342/com.grgapps.checkingin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.grgapps.checkingin, PID: 5342
    java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bf.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@16089052@16.0.89 (040700-239467275):569)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.l.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@16089052@16.0.89 (040700-239467275):361)
        at fw.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@16089052@16.0.89 (040700-239467275):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzg.setMyLocationEnabled(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(Unknown Source)
        at com.grgapps.checkingin.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:64)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzak.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
        at fv.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@16089052@16.0.89 (040700-239467275):14)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bd.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@16089052@16.0.89 (040700-239467275):4)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bk.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@16089052@16.0.89 (040700-239467275):4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Search on google `java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

Comment: Your understanding regarding permissions is incorrect. It's the absolute opposite of the reality, i.e. on SDK version 23 and higher, you *need* to ask for permission before accessing location

Comment: I have done that for the last few hours and have not found a resolution.  It appears I have followed what is required.

Comment: OK, I added the logic to request permission and that worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As per Android Document:**

*Android 6.0 Marshmallow introduced a new permissions model that lets apps request permissions from the user at runtime, rather than prior to installation. Apps that support the new model request permissions when the app actually requires the services or data protected by the services. While this doesn't (necessarily) change overall app behavior, it does create a few changes relevant to the way sensitive user data is handled:*

For SDK version 23, you need to ask run time permission to access the device location. For that, please call `enableMyLocation()` method in `onCreate()` function